# How to move existing git repository to new repository and preserve commit history

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to move/clone repository into new location, migrate it from BitBucket to GitLab. I want to move all branches and preserve commit history.

I'd like to know if there is a way to do that via SourceTree or simply by command.
I tried searching for an answer but couldn't find a single, easy to understand tutorial.

Comment: You have the full explanation in Gitlab help: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/bitbucket.html

Comment: I am specificly asking for solution where I could use Source Tree or Command line.

Comment: Ok. I thought you just wrote those 2 as example for options

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a blank repository set up in GitLab;

```
git remote add gitlab <gitlab_repo_url>
git push --all gitlab
```